Solving a set of coupled ordinary differential equation representing the coupled Chua oscillator with solve_ivp
I am trying to write a python code to solve the ODE representing a coupled Chua oscillators. The set of ODEs can be found here.
The non-linear term is defined as  f(x)
And the possible solution is given here.
For two Chua oscillators coupled bidirectionally via the (x)-variable, the ODEs are modified to include coupling terms. Let ((x_1, y_1, z_1)) represent the state variables of the first oscillator and ((x_2, y_2, z_2)) represent the state variables of the second oscillator. The coupled system can be written as:
For the first Chua oscillator:
\frac{dx_1}{dt} = \alpha \left( y_1 - x_1 - f(x_1) \right) + \kappa (x_2 - x_1)
\frac{dy_1}{dt} = x_1 - y_1 + z_1
\frac{dz_1}{dt} = -\beta y_1

For the second Chua oscillator:
\frac{dx_2}{dt} = \alpha \left( y_2 - x_2 - f(x_2) \right) + \kappa (x_1 - x_2)
\frac{dy_2}{dt} = x_2 - y_2 + z_2
\frac{dz_2}{dt} = -\beta y_2

Here:

(\kappa) is the coupling strength between the two oscillators,
(f(x)) is the same nonlinear function for both oscillators, typically defined as:

f(x) = m_1 x + 0.5 (m_0 - m_1) \left( |x + 1| - |x - 1| \right)

where (m_0) and (m_1) are parameters of the piecewise-linear Chua diode characteristic.
The coupling term (\kappa (x_2 - x_1)) introduces bidirectional coupling between the oscillators.
The article is available on: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Makoto_Itoh/publication/263913998_Chaos_synchronization_in_Chua's_Circuit/links/58a7e92192851cf0e3b97b0f/Chaos-synchronization-in-Chuas-Circuit.pdf?_tp=eyJjb250ZXh0Ijp7ImZpcnN0UGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uIiwicGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uIn19
I have written the code as follows:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the nonlinear function f for Chua's circuit
def f(u, m0, m1):
    return m1*u + (m0 - m1)/2 * (np.abs(u + 1) - np.abs(u - 1))

# Define the ODE system for two coupled Chua oscillators
def Chua_dr(t, X, ep, alpha, beta, m0, m1):
    x, y, z, xp, yp, zp = X
    w = ep * (x - xp)  # Coupling term
    return [
        alpha*(y - x - f(x, m0, m1)) - w,  # First oscillator equations
        x - y + z,
        -beta * y,
        alpha*(yp - xp - f(xp, m0, m1)) + w,  # Second oscillator equations
        xp - yp + zp,
        -beta * yp
    ]

# Solve the ODE system
def sol_dr(t, T, ep, alpha, y0_dr):
    sol = solve_ivp(
        Chua_dr, [0, T], y0_dr, 
        args=(ep, alpha, beta, m0, m1), method='LSODA', 
        dense_output=True, rtol=1e-9, atol=1e-12)
    return sol.sol(t)

# Parameters for Chua oscillators
alpha, beta, m0, m1 = 10, 14.87, -1.27, -0.68
ep = 0.15 # Coupling strength

# Initial conditions for the system
y0_dr = [-2, 0.2, 4, 0.7, 0.4, -0.8] 
# Generate time array 
T = 500
t = np.linspace(100, T, (T-100)*100+1)

# Solve the system and plot the results
sol = sol_dr(t, T, ep, alpha, y0_dr)

The numerical solution diverges for coupling value ep>0.12. I have tried few things, such as changing integratin method for solve_ivp from default RK45 to LSODA suitable for stiff ODEs, integrating for shorter time span and using the last value as the initial condition to further the integration ahead. But all gives the same result. The concerned article on the other hand shows results with nice attractor with synchronised manifold for all values of ep.

You may want to add the code to draw your plots, @Faruque, so that it is clearer what the problem is. One of your initial conditions is slightly different to that in the paper, although it makes no substantive difference to the behaviour. I agree, the code is incredibly sensitive to a small change in EP (or to the nonlinear function f). Given that this paper has over 300 citations can you check what other people have done with it?

The paper says that convergence is only forced for ep > 0.5, theoretically for ep > 5.5. Do you get results for those parameters? // LSODA is also based on explicit methods, only with varying order. Radau is implicit, and perhaps some of the lower order methods. DOP853 also reacts better to stiff problems than most other explicit methods.

It certainly works for EP=5.5, giving a result not unlike the sample plots. However, it seems to blow up for EP=0.5, the value claimed for the sample plots. They are incredibly stiff equations.
